# Not able to resolve AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT' while installing django dependencies

Tags: django, xcode, python-2.7

### Using MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Installing Django project dependencies from requirement.txt file

```
sudo pip install --user -r requirement.txt
```

I have looked over internet for the similar issues but none of them helped.
I even have tried uninstalling pyOpenSSL using command:

```
pip uninstall pyOpenSSL
```

even this command is giving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==19.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/RitZz/Desktop/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 124, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

At few place it is mentioned to use:

```
sudo easy_install -U pyopenssl/pyOpenSSL
```

still getting same error.
even after deleting manually

#### > pyopenssl from python/2.7/site-packages/

and then reinstalling using command:

```
sudo pip install pyopenssl
```

it is not working, giving same error, (have also tried commands using --user flag)